# Reload if no www. is present via HTACCESS

Tags: .htaccess

Currently we do it per site in the .htaccess, is there away to regex this piece of code up?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^soupandcookies.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.soupandcookies.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^soupandcookies-takeaway.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.soupandcookies-takeaway.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

As it has been a chore as we are starting to us ALOT of domains on one codebase.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For non-HTTPS requests:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And for HTTPS requests:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Also note that relying on `HTTP_HOST` is unsecure. Its value is taken from the HTTP header field `Host: ...` which can be forged, if your default vhost handles all requests.